# Python Score Invalid Syntax Wont work

Tags: python

```
if score <=30:
 print = "You have scored:" + score + ":("

else score > = 31 and < = 60
 print = "You have scored:" + score + ":/"

elif score < = 61
 print = "You have scored:" + score + ":)"
```

I am making a quiz in python and i need it so that when the score is between 0-30,30-60 and 60+, a different message is shown, although i tried the code above and it keeps saying invalid syntax.

Comment: `elif score >= 31 and score <= 60` instead of `else score > = 31 and < = 60`

Comment: You also need colons after your `elif` conditions

Comment: it continues to say invalid syntax

Comment: Also you need `elif score >= 31 and score <= 60`.  It's two separate condition checks.

Answer (score 0):

It's because score variable is an integer so you can't print it like that. Try this, the stuff you are printing should be in brackets, not "=". Also after if statements there should be a ":" . Try this:

```
if score <=30:
     print("You have scored:" + str(score) + ":(")

elif score >= 31 and score <= 60:
     print("You have scored:" + str(score) + ":/")

elif score <= 61:
     print("You have scored:" + str(score) + ":)")
```

Answer (score -2):

```
else score > = 31 and score <= 60
```

Needs to be

```
elif score > = 31 and score <= 60:
```

And you need to add a `:` to the last elif too. And your print statements are wrong. The syntax is `print 'hello'` or `print('hello')` depending on python version. You should really look at beginner python syntax stuff

Comment: @kindall ye I just noticed how much was wrong with the original syntax...